# how to make an object move up and down in pygame automatically?

Tags: python, pygame

i want to make my block move up and down move on its own but its not moving as every time the while loop runs the value resets to 400. I have a similar program where i apply same concept for x direction and it works but this doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
class Level4():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=400
        self.vel=10
    def platform(self):
        self.move()
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 85, 20), (400, self.y, 150, 20))
    def move(self):
        self.y-=self.vel
        if self.y<10 or self.y > 400:
            self.vel*=-1
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I think you are not checking when your character touches the gound. And there are some strange things in your code. Check this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-making-an-object-jump-in-pygame/

Comment: I agree with @pedro_bb7 there's a lot of messy and overcomplicated logic in your code.  Try thinking through it carefully.  For example you have a `gravity()` method that's supposed to pull the player back down, but it seems to be called only once.  Can't be sure though since your indentation is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects. Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

class Level():
    def __init__(self, rect, yrange, vel):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.yrange = yrange
        self.vel = vel
        self.direction = -1

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y += self.vel * self.direction
        
        if self.rect.top <= self.yrange[0]:
            self.rect.top = self.yrange[0]
            self.direction = 1    
        if self.rect.bottom >= self.yrange[1]:
            self.rect.bottom = self.yrange[1]
            self.direction = -1  

    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (200, 85, 20), self.rect)

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

block = Level((200, 400, 150, 20), [10, 400], 5)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    block.move()

    win.fill(0)
    block.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```